# Python Functions Approximating Pi

Tags: python, function, for-loop, math, pi

I am part of saylor.org free intro to python course and i'm stuck on a problem in their Unit 5 Quiz:

Instructions attached in an image:

[image]

I was able to get the basic code down but I cannot figure out a way to add (√2+)'s within the for loop it asks for.

Here's the code I have:

```
import math
def pi_approx(N):
    for i in range(N):
        print(V=(math.sqrt(2)/2)*N(math.sqrt(2)+math.sqrt(2))/2)
    pi_est=2/V
    x=math.fabs(pi_est-math.pi)
    if x < 1e-7:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The expected result: `True`

Comment: You shouldn't have `print()` around your variable assignment.

Comment: In fact isn't that an error?  I don't see how this code even runs...

Comment: @barmar I had the print around the variable assignment to test what the output was that I got, and forgot to take it off before posting this my bad

Answer (score 1):

You're reassigning `V` each time through the loop. But the formula says you have to multiply each element in the series, so use `V *=` to reassign the variable with multiplication.

You can't put `print()` around an assignment. That doesn't assign the variable, it's using `V=` as a named function argument. If you want to see the variable's value, put `print(V)` *after* you assign to it.

You're not doing all the nested square roots that are needed. You need a nested loop to calculate the repeated square roots in each term, before dividing by 2.

```
import math

def pi_approx(N):
    V = 1
    for i in range(1, N):
        radical = 0
        for j in range(i):
            radical = math.sqrt(2 + radical)
        V *= radical / 2
    pi_est=2/V
    print(pi_est)
    x=math.fabs(pi_est-math.pi)
    if x < 1e-7:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(pi_approx(20))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need the inner for loop if you hold onto the radical between iterations of the outer loop.

Comment: I had a feeling there was a relationship I was missing.

Comment: I'll upvote your answer rather than revising mine.

Answer (score 1):

The helpful insight is that with each iteration you can use the old numerator to calculate the new numerate:

```
next_numerator = math.sqrt(2 + old_numerator)
```

If you keep the numerator and the running product as separate values, you can do the entire calculation in a single loop:

```
import math

def aprox_pi(n):
    numerator = math.sqrt(2)
    prod = numerator / 2
    
    for _ in range(1,n):
        numerator = math.sqrt(2 + numerator)
        prod *= numerator / 2
    
    return 2 / prod


assert aprox_pi(1) == 2 / (math.sqrt(2) / 2) 
assert aprox_pi(2) == 2 / ((math.sqrt(2) / 2) * (math.sqrt(2 + math.sqrt(2)) / 2)) 
assert aprox_pi(3) == 2 / ((math.sqrt(2) / 2) * (math.sqrt(2 + math.sqrt(2)) / 2) * (math.sqrt(2 + math.sqrt(2 + math.sqrt(2)))) / 2)
# etc
```

With that, you should be able to insert your test to determine the delta between your approximation and `math.pi`. It seems to converge well before an `N >= 100`

```
aprox_pi(20)
# 3.1415926535886185
```

One small note on style: the `<` operator creates a boolean, so you can just return that:

instead of:

```
if x < 1e-7:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

just return:

```
return x < 1e-7
```